# Cambiar valor específico de un input datetime con JS

Tags: javascript, html, navegador-web

Quiero preguntar si es posible cambiar los valores por defecto a escoger en un input de tipo datetime, específicamente la hora y los minutos. Cómo se muestra en la imagen, me da para escoger entre las 24 horas del día y los 60 minutos también, pero, por ejemplo, pregunto si es posible hacerlo cada 10 minutos, siendo 10, 20, 30, 40 y 50 los valores a escoger:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que con el atributo step puedo obtener un resultado similar, pero busco saber si es posible hacerlo desde el lugar que indico.

```
<input name="input_fecha" type="datetime-local" step="600">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu te encuentras en lo peor de 2 mundos. El manejo de fechas en javascript es horrible y la customización de componentes nativos es casi inexistente.

El `step` en los `datetime-local` solo funciona cuando la entrada es por teclado y usas las flechas arriba y abajo. No cambia lista de elementos en la ventana modal. (cosa que estoy casi seguro que alguna vez si ocurría). Obviamente todo esto dependerá finalmente del navegador, por lo que el comportamiento varia siempre

Para setear el atributo `step` por javascript solo debes hacer:

```js
const UnInput = document.getElementById("uninput");
UnInput.step = "600";
```

```html
<input id="uninput" name="input_fecha" type="datetime-local">
```

Ahora también puedes crear una función que redondeé los minutos cuando el usuario ha seleccionado una fecha/hora

Algo así:

```js
function redondear(){
  const factor = Number(event.target.step) / 60;
  let valor = new Date(event.target.value);
  
  if(valor.getMinutes() % factor != 0){
     const min_round = Math.round(valor.getMinutes() / 10) * 10;
     let now = new Date()
     valor.setMinutes(min_round - now.getTimezoneOffset());
     event.target.value =valor.toISOString().slice(0, 19);
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="input_fecha" type="datetime-local" oninput="redondear()" step="600">
```